# Binary search tree preorder algorithm in OCaml

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble implementing this algorithm in OCaml since I must print parentheses in between the function.

The algorithm goes like this:

```
BEGIN
   WRITE ( "(" )
   IF (NOT EMPTY tree) THEN 
      IF (NOT EMPTY (left_leaf tree)) OR (NOT EMPTY (right_leaf tree)) THEN BEGIN
        WRITE (" ", root tree, " ")
        preorder (left_leaf tree)
        WRITE (" ")
        preorder (right_leaf tree)
      END ELSE
        WRITE (" ", root tree, " ")
   WRITE ( ")" ); {this has to be always executed}
END
```

This is my poor attempt in OCaml:

```
let rec preorderParenthesed tree = 

   print_string "(" in
   if not (isEmptyTree tree) then (
      if not (isEmptyTree(leftLeaf tree)) || not (isEmptyTree(rightLeaf tree)) then begin
        print_string " ";
        print_string (string_of_root (root tree));
        print_string " ";
        preorderParenthesed (leftLeaf tree);
        print_string " ";
        preorderParenthesed (rightLeaf tree);
      end else
        print_string " ";
        print_string (string_of_root (root tree));
        print_string " "; 
    ) 
    else if true then print_string ")\n";;
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
type bst = 
Empty   
| Node of (key * bst * bst);;
```

Comment: Can you give an simple example with the expected output? Also, can you show us how you define your tree structure?

Comment: Yes.

1) Empty tree -> ( )
2) Tree A, Empty leafs -> (A)
3) Tree A, B left leaf, C right leaf -> ( A ( B ) ( C ) )
4) Tree A, B left leaf, Empty leaf -> ( A ( B ) ( ) )

Please check the question again to see the type structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can get a lot simpler using pattern-matching:

```
type 'a bst = Empty | Node of ('a * 'a bst * 'a bst)

let rec string_of_tree ~f = function
| Empty ->
  "()"
| Node (value, Empty, Empty) ->
  Printf.sprintf "(%s)" (f value)
| Node (value, left, right) ->
  Printf.sprintf "(%s %s %s)"
    (f value)
    (string_of_tree ~f left)
    (string_of_tree ~f right)

val string_of_tree : f:('a -> string) -> 'a bst -> string = <fun>
```

> `f` is simply a `string_of_*` function.

The patterns describe the following cases:

1. The tree is empty

   - `()`
2. The tree is not empty, but both sub-trees are

   - `(value)`
3. The tree is not empty, and case 2. didn't check

   - `(value left_subtree right_subtree)`

Comment: That's amazing. Couldn't have thought of something like that after seeing the structure of the algorithm. Thank you.

Comment: It's only a matter of training. Once you get used to that way of thinking, that kind of things comes naturally. You might be interested in [99 problems in OCaml](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you omitted the begin/end in the else branch :

```
  end else
    print_string " ";
    print_string (string_of_root (root tree));
    print_string " ";
```

Comment: Hi Pierre G., being sincere with you I am not acquainted with the begin and end in ocaml since it's the very first time I try to do a function using them and also using lines ending with ";" which I am still not sure how that works.

Comment: if you do not encapsulate the 3 print_string hereabove in a begin/end, the else branch of the if/then/else will execute only print_string "". But what you want is to execute the sequence of the 3 print_string as a unique block - this is what begin/end does (or as you did elsewhere in your code : open and close parenthesis do the same as begin/end).

Answer (score 2):

Preorder Traversal can be a little confusing but here's a little overview of how it works:

1. Visit the current node
2. Traverse the left subtree
3. Traverse the right subtree

In your code I think you're implementing the traversal and doing the work at the same time, it may be simpler to separate the two:

```
let rec traversePreOrder node cb =
  match node with
  | Empty  -> "()"
  | Node (value, left, right) ->
      cb value; 
      traversePreOrder left cb; 
      traversePreOrder right cb;
```

Where you can traverse the nodes using the steps above and invoke the callback(a function that can print the value of the node) as you visit a node.